# strange characters appear in GIT cmd

Tags: git, encoding, cmd, hebrew

I installed Git-2.9.3.2-64-bit, but in GIT CMD it is displaying strange characters in hebrew (i guess). I installed it with the default options selected.
Could you please let me know how I can change it to Latin characters so it makes sense to me?

[image: GIT CMD snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try the same git command after:

```
set LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Or in the bash shell:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If that does work, then you can add the export line to `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc`.